# How to format which is in String to java format

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am developing a wizard page. In that page i am converting a file into String and displaying it in the text box

But I want to display the text in a java format I have tried with the below code

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ToolFactory;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.MalformedTreeException;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;
    public class FormatterTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String code = pagehandlerContent; //the file which im getting and saving it in string
            CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);
            TextEdit textEdit = codeFormatter.format(CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, code, 0, code.length(), 0, null);
            IDocument doc = new Document(code);
            try {
                textEdit.apply(doc);
                System.out.println(doc.get());
            } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

but I am getting null pointer exception at textEdit.apply(doc) line
pagehandlercontent contains a file which is converted into string format
textEdit.apply(doc) is not accepting some special characters. that is the reason im getting null pointer exception.
Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: _"But I want to display the text in a java format"_ What do you mean with that?

Comment: I am getting the file and converting it in to string, and in swt text box im displaying the string                                  I want the text to be  displayed in proper java format

Comment: You mean something like indentation or code highlighting?

Comment: From the `CodeFormatter.format()` javadoc: It returns null if the given string cannot be formatted. It would be helpful if you include more information about your `pagehandlerContent`.

Comment: I am parsing a java file into a string, pagehandlercontent contains the string and when i am printing it in the textbox it is not coming in proper java form. I want to get that string in java format

Comment: What is _"java format"_??

Comment: `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatterApplication` uses very similar code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(string)
```